# Are questions about design patterns at fault for being "primarily opinion-based"?

Tags: discussion, support, needs-more-focus, opinion-based

Earlier today, I asked a question about the design pattern of WordPress. With astonishing speed, it was "put on hold as primarily opinion-based." However, it seemed to me that was I asking a clearly objective question. Just as one might ask about the design pattern of Drupal (PAC) or the design pattern of Ruby on Rails (MVC), I asked about the design pattern of WordPress. Given that I can't see anything subjective and opinion-based in the question, I am baffled that it was "put on hold" so quickly.

I have deleted the original SO post and have migrated it to the [WordPress Stack Exchange site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/169812/what-is-the-design-pattern-for-wordpress-core).

In short, are questions about design patterns too broad, too opinion-based, or too subjective for Stack Overflow? If the answer is yes, then so follows this obvious corollary: where *should* questions about design patterns be asked?

Comment: The question better should have been closed as _too broad_ instead of _opinion based_ , since I'd supposed there's a vast number of different design patterns (in the sense of GoF design patterns, or other catalogues), to actually implement something complex like `WordPress`.

Comment: Since you deleted the question, it's very difficult for any of us non-10k+ users to chime in with an opinion here.

Comment: @jfmercer If you still have access to the question, you should at least copy its text into the meta question. It's impossible to judge what the flaw was without it.

Comment: "Warmly received" seems an exaggeration. It has two comments which effectively state the same thing as SO: it's too broad. The fact that they haven't closed it yet might simply be because they receive much less traffic than SO does. But if you think SO is overly hostile (an assertion I still don't agree with), start a separate meta question about it.

Answer (score 6):

> *"In short, are questions about design patterns too broad ..."*

Not in general, but for this particular question and context they are.

There's no single *Design Pattern* that can be considered for describing a complex application like `WordPress` as mentioned.

Any non trivial application will be build up using a number of design patterns to be used in it's components and interfaces it's based on.

Your question is way too broad to give a concise answer on SO.

Comment: @jfmercer Complex frameworks and applications, such as those you've mentioned, evolve (hopefully) with a guiding _architecture_, which may involve the use of multiple _design patterns_.  Rather than having a specific question about _one_ of the basic patterns that are used to build an application architecture, it sounds to me like you want to discuss the architectural design of the whole -- and that's too broad of a scope for a question on SO.

Comment: **Moderator Note**: Please keep the conversation civil. Linking someone to a post that says, "Don't be an asshole" is the equivalent of calling a person an asshole. That's not welcome here.  Discuss the merits of the argument, not the person raising it.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I don't get it? Was there a comment I didn't see, and it was deleted meanwhile? I'm pretty sure I didn't give such link.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ it wasn't a comment by you that was flagged. It was another issue that has been addressed.

Answer (score 5):

I think there's a disconnect with what Stack Overflow actually is and what is generally thought it's for.  For users coming from forums or other traditional 'anything goes' discussion groups on the internet, Stack Exchange is a strange beast.  We're not a traditional 'anything goes' forum. We're a Q&A site.

To that end,

We have two goals:

- Get users help for their specific programming problems
- Become a repository of useful programming knowledge on the internet

We expect the former to help us accomplish the latter.  If it does not, it will be closed.  We are not meant to house all possible programming questions. We've chosen to narrow our scope to programming questions that fulfill both goals above.

We [have a number of generally accepted reasons for closing a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-or-on-hold-question).

Your question was closed because it was 'too broad' (in that there are too many possible correct answers to that question) or it could have been closed as 'primarily opinion based' because people could disagree vociferously about why/what programming patterns were used (if any were indeed used).

That's why it was closed.

At this juncture, you have three options:

1. Leave the question as is; appeal to meta and hope five people (or one moderator) agree that it meets Goals #1 and #2, and does not meet any of the criteria for closure; thus re-opening it.
2. Edit your question to narrow its scope and reduce its opinion-based nature.  I have no idea how to do this for your particular question.
3. Ask meta how this question could be made better; and then edit it to address the concerns raised.

So to answer your general question:  Questions are closed if they meet the criteria for closure and if they don't further goals #1 and #2; and we can't give a general answer for all design patterns questions because each question is judged individually on its merits.

In general, asking about a program's architecture is too broad for us; entire books have been written about a program's architecture, it's unreasonable to expect a few paragraphs on Stack Overflow to do it justice.

Comment: Worth noting for this question, "too broad" can also mean "there's one correct answer but it's too long to fit into a Q&A format", right?

Comment: @ChrisHayes Correct.  From the close dialog for too broad: "There are either too many possible answers, **or good answers would be too long for this format.** Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs." (emphasis added)

Comment: @jfmercer The general architectural pattern that the framework RoR implements is "MVC"; same with drupal.  Both frameworks use a ton of design patterns in their construction.  Since wordpress.com is not a programming framework, it'd be impossible to answer which 'architectural pattern' it implements, since it's not a framework for creating software.  Incidentally, we have a Stack Overflow question covering Architectural vs. Design patterns: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243187/difference-between-design-pattern-and-architecture